# aws s3 sync on a 7TB folder hangs forever

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync around 7TB from a non EC2 instance to S3.
So fare I have managed to sync a 500GB folder in something like 3hours. Which is quite good.

However, I'm now trying to sync a 7TB folder and it just get stuck. It has been now 1hour and the debug logs are stuck here:

```
2018-06-01 18:05:05,983 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2018-06-01 18:05:05,987 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2018-06-01 18:05:05,989 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2018-06-01 18:05:05,989 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
2018-06-01 18:05:05,990 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.s3handler - DEBUG - Using a multipart threshold of 8388608 and a part size of 8388608
2018-06-01 18:05:05,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choosing-s3-sync-strategy: calling handler <bound method SizeOnlySync.use_sync_strategy of <awscli.customizations.s3.syncstrategy.sizeonly.SizeOnlySync object at 0x7f5f42a9acd0>>
2018-06-01 18:05:05,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choosing-s3-sync-strategy: calling handler <bound method ExactTimestampsSync.use_sync_strategy of <awscli.customizations.s3.syncstrategy.exacttimestamps.ExactTimestampsSync object at 0x7f5f42a9a790>>
2018-06-01 18:05:05,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choosing-s3-sync-strategy: calling handler <bound method DeleteSync.use_sync_strategy of <awscli.customizations.s3.syncstrategy.delete.DeleteSync object at 0x7f5f42a9aa50>>
```

Is the cli having trouble listing all the files and dies?

Comment: I am having the same issue, its erroring out on  "2020-01-06 10:19:44,028 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.s3handler - DEBUG - Using a multipart threshold of 8388608 and a part size of 8388608"

Comment: Issue was the hard drive. Some folder couldn't be read

Comment: thanks Marco, My issue was with incorrect policy